# Cannot clone git repo via https on gitlab

Tags: git, authentication, clone, gitlab

I created a test project on gitlab but when I try to clone the repo I get this error.

```
Cloning into 'testperm'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/MYUSER/testperm.git/'
```

However if i change the permission on the repo to  (Visibility Level) Public I can clone. 
To test my user and password I copied the repo https url and pasted in my browser and logged in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Change the clone url to ssh and you wont need any username password any more.

Set the ssh keys on your machine and then change the url of the cloned repository to the `ssh` protocol `git@....`

Once your keys are set correctly you should not see the username password again.

***`P.S`***
Once you set your keys and you have updated the repository url do a first time fetch/pull so your key will be added to the known_hosts file. (answer yes when prompt)

Comment: This wont work for me , I can only access gitlab from my work network via https.